# XenForo: How do I set @imagePath?

Tags: html, css, forum, xenforo

I'm trying to make my own theme, and I can't find the way to set @imagePath for the life of me. Can someone please tell me how to see it? (It's currently pointing to the default theme's directory)

Answer (score 2):

It is set under *Appearance -> Style Properties -> General -> Path to Images* in Xenforo admin.